# How to convert bytes to str in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, byte, amazon-kinesis

I am reading this record off a kinesis stream and I see this problem:

```
event: {'Records': [{'kinesis': {'kinesisSchemaVersion': '1.0', 'partitionKey': '1', 'sequenceNumber': '49598713911021236248095996540994479657456990259863617538', 'data': 'SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lg==', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1566421493.064}, 'eventSource': 'aws:kinesis', 'eventVersion': '1.0',

[ERROR] TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 11, in extract     print("raw = " + raw)
```

This is my code:

```py
print("context: ", context)
print("event: ", event)

for record in event['Records']:
    raw = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data'])
    print("raw = " + raw)
```

Why does it fail at `raw = " + raw`? Isn't it a string?

Answer (score 0):

[`b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) returns `bytes` so you will need to decode this into `str` before trying to do concatenation.

For your example:

```py
print("context: ", context)
print("event: ", event)

for record in event['Records']:
    raw = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print("raw = " + raw)
```